# Nothing wasn't display in http://localhost:3333/ with lwc-dev-server

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, lwc-dev-server

I'm trying to use lwc local development with the following steps in my developer experience.

1. Install lwc-dev-server with "sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server".
2. Updated with "sfdx update".
3. Start the local server with "sfdx force:lightning:lwc:start".

Dev Hub had already enabled and created scratch org for this test. Typed this command(reference at No.3) with no problems but wasn't displayed anything at http://localhost:3333/. How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually the first time takes about a minute or two depending on number of components you have. You should see it in the log in vscode after you navigate to the localhost url. Also you can try `127.0 0.1:3333`, if this works then its probably a mapping issue in hosts file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is personal firewall setting of ESET. After I disabled this setting, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is personal firewall setting of ESET. After I disabled this setting, everything is OK.